# copying data from one array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Array One:

```
 array1 = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aaaaa",
        "attr": [{"attr_code": "a_id", "value": "5"}]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "attr": [{"attr": "a_id", "value": "4"}]
      }]
```

Array Two:

```
array2 = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bef",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "bcd",
  }]
```

Resulting Array:

```
 resultingArray =  [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "attr": [{"attr_code": "a_id", "value": "5"}],
    "a_id" :   {"id": 5, "name": "bcd"}
  },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bbbbb",
      "attr": [{"attr": "a_id", "value": "4"}],
      "a_id" : {"id": 4, "name": "bef"}
    }]
```

I am looking to add the array2 objects into array1 based on id's of array2. I have tried using map function on both the arrays to compare and add the object but I didn't succeed. Can you please suggest me how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the array2 objects into array1 based on ids of array2.

```js
let array1 = 
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "attr": [{"attr_code": "a_id", "value": "5"}]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bbbbb",
    "attr": [{"attr": "a_id", "value": "4"}]
  }
];
      
let array2 = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bef",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "bcd",
  }
];
 
let resultingArray=[]; 

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  element['a_id'] = [];
  element['attr'].forEach(function(attr) {
        element['a_id'].push(array2.find(function(item) {
        return item.id == attr.value;
      }));
   });
  resultingArray.push(element)
});

console.log(resultingArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you intend to extract the object whose ID is equal to the `value` field the in the each object in `array1`.

```
var array1 = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aaaaa",
        "attr": [{"attr_code": "a_id", "value": "5"}]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "attr": [{"attr": "a_id", "value": "4"}]
      }];

var array2 = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bef",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "bcd",
  }];

var resultingArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    resultingArray[i] = array1[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if(resultingArray[i].attr[0].attr_code.value === array2[j].id) {
            resultingArray[i].push("a_id": array2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to lop through `array1`, and for each object in `array1`, you need to find corresponding objects in `array2` which match the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array map and array index to do:

```js
var array1 = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aaaaa",
        "attr": [{"attr_code": "a_id", "value": "5"}]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "attr": [{"attr": "a_id", "value": "4"}]
      }];
var array2 = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bef",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "bcd",
  }];
var result = array1.map(current=>{
  //find index of attr in array2
  let index = array2.findIndex(c=>{
    if (c['id']===(Number(current['attr'][0]['value'])))
      return c;
  });
  current["a_id"] = array2[index];
  return current;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following code suites your requirement. You may need to make some changes.

```
function mergeArrays3 (arr1, arr2) {
 return arr1.map((value, index) => {
  let object = null;
  let result = {...value};
  for (let element of arr2) {
   if (element.id == parseInt(value.attr[0].value)) {
    object = element;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (object != null) {
   let attr = value.attr[0];
   if (attr.hasOwnProperty("attr")) {
    result[value.attr[0].attr] = object;
   } else if (attr.hasOwnProperty("attr_code")) {
    result[value.attr[0].attr_code] = object;
   }
  }
  return result;
 });
}
```

I loop over first array and find an element in second array matching id of  value.attr[0].value. If found then i added this object in the first array at key of value.attr[0].attr or value.attr[0].attr_code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using map function on both the arrays to compare and add
>   the object but I didn't succeed

Below is the functional programming approach using map():

```js
/* GIVEN */
const array1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "attr": [{
      "attr_code": "a_id",
      "value": "5"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bbbbb",
    "attr": [{
      "attr": "a_id",
      "value": "4"
    }]
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bef",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "bcd",
  }]

/* From array2, make an object keyed by the 'id' field. We'll use this as a key-value lookup table  */
const lookupTable = array2.reduce((accum, item) => {
    accum[item.id.toString()] = item
    return accum
  }, {})
  
  
console.log('***LOOKUP TABLE***\n', lookupTable) // result is an object we use to lookup

/* From array1, we append data from the lookup table */
const final = array1.map(item => {
    item.a_id = lookupTable[item.attr[0].value]
    return item
  })

console.log("***RESULT***\n", final)
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,